# Upper bounds for Lyapunov equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Consider the Lyapunov equation
$$
 AX+XA^T+I=0
$$
for the given stable matrix $A$.

Is it possible to obtain the upper estimation for $\|X\|$ (in spectral or Frobenius norm) in terms of $A$?

Comment: What is $\|X\|$? Does $\|\cdot\|$ denote the [induced norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms) or the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm)?

Comment: Here $\|\cdot\|$ means spectral or Frobenius norm.

Answer (score 2):

For the spectral norm: it is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation) that the unique solution to this equation can be expressed as
$$
X = \int_0^\infty e^{At}e^{A^Tt}\,dt.
$$
We note that
$$
\|X\| = \left\|\int_0^\infty e^{At}e^{A^Tt}\,dt \right\| \leq
\int_0^\infty \left\|e^{At}e^{A^Tt}\right\|\,dt
= \int_0^\infty \|e^{At}\|^2\,dt
$$
Let $\alpha$ denote the maximum value of $\operatorname{Re}(\lambda)$ among the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$. There exists a constant $C > 0$ such that $\|e^{At}\| \leq C \cdot e^{\alpha t}$ (in particular, if $A$ is diagonalizable and $SAS^{-1}$ is diagonal, then $C$ can be taken to be the condition number of $S$). By the stability of $A$, we must have $\alpha < 0$. With that, we have
$$
\| X\| \leq \int_0^\infty \|e^{At}\|^2\,dt \leq C\int_0^\infty e^{2 \alpha t}\,dt = \frac C{2|\alpha|}.
$$

---

For the Frobenius norm: we can write
$$
\operatorname{vec}(X) = -(I_n \otimes A + A \otimes I_n)^{-1} \operatorname{vec}(I).
$$
It follows that
$$
\|X\|_F = \|\operatorname{vec}(X)\| = \|(I_n \otimes A + A \otimes I_n)^{-1} \operatorname{vec}(I_n)\| 
\\ \leq \|(I_n \otimes A + A \otimes I_n)^{-1}\| \cdot \|\operatorname{vec}(I_n)\|
\\ \leq \|(I_n \otimes A +  A \otimes I_n)^{-1}\| \cdot \sqrt{n}.
$$
Let $S$ be such that $D = S^{-1}AS$ is diagonal. We note that
$$
\|(I_n \otimes A + A \otimes I)^{-1}\| = \\
(S \otimes S)^{-1}(I \otimes D + D \otimes I)^{-1}(S \otimes S) \leq \\
\|(S \otimes S)^{-1}\|\cdot\|(I \otimes D + D \otimes I)^{-1}\| \cdot \|S \otimes S\| =\\
\|S^{-1}\|^2 \cdot \|(I \otimes D + D \otimes I)^{-1}\| \cdot \|S\|^2.
$$
Let $\alpha$ denote the maximum value of $\operatorname{Re}(\lambda)$ among the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$. Let $C$ denote the condition number of $S$, i.e. $C = \|S\|\cdot\|S\|^{-1}$. We have
$$
\|(I \otimes D + D \otimes I)^{-1}\| \leq \frac 1{2|\alpha|},
$$
so that $\|X\|_F \leq \frac{C^2}{2|\alpha|}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! But what is $\bar A$? Is it $A^T$?

Comment: And could we estimate $\|(I_n\otimes A+\bar A\otimes I_n)^{-1}\|$ via $A$?

Comment: @mm12 I got rid of the bar. $\bar A$ is the complex-conjugate of $A$, which is irrelevant because your matrices have real entries

Comment: @mm12 We could probably do something similar with condition numbers for that estimate

Comment: @mm12 See my latest edit